# UITableView reloadSections creates a sectionheader on top of a row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with one sectionheader. With the following codesnippet I reload the tableview when a user swipes the view left or right.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

When a user has scolled downwards in the tableview and then swipes, this codesnippet reloads the rows correctly but the sectionheader is created on top of the row where the swipe was initiated.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong & how to solve ?

thanks
Frank

Comment: What style is the table view set to?  Group or Plain?

Comment: hello aBitObvious, the style is plain. I've still not been able to solve so suggestions are welcome. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `reloadSections:withRowAnimation` seems to be buggy on iOS 4.0, and it was fixed in one of the later versions.

On iOS 4.0 calling `reloadSections:withRowAnimation` results in table header appearing in the middle of a row, and on 4.3 it works fine. I've replaced it with `reloadData` which is less optimal, but works on 4.0 too.